# How to determine the size of the longest ticklabels to use in the startposition of a line

Tags: python, matplotlib, line, transform

In this graph I want a horizontal line between the horizontal detailbars and the totalbar.

The line needs to start at the same position as the first character of the yticklabel of the longest label.

In the example below, I've tried different values myself and optically determined that the used value was ok in this case, but if the longest label was not 'second', but for example 'twentyfirst', then the startposition of the black line would start even more on the left.

How can this be determined or calculated automatically?

I've tried searching for solutions, but this seems a very specific subject.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Gegevens voor de balken
bartitles = ["First", "Second", "Third"]
barvalues = [4, 3, 5]
total_value = sum(barvalues)

# Figure and axes
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Plot bars
y_pos = list(range(1,4))
ax.barh(y_pos, barvalues, align='center', color='darkgrey')


# Totalbar
y_pos_total = 0  # Position of the totalbar
ax.barh(y_pos_total, total_value, align='center', color='blue')
bartitles.append("Total")
y_pos.append(y_pos_total)

# plot ticks and titles
ax.set_yticks(y_pos)
ax.set_yticklabels(bartitles)

# Line which starts outside the horizontal barchart
start_position = -0.115  # Value after optical trying different values to get the start equal to the 'S' of 'Second'
# How can this start_position be calculated when the barnames have other lenghts?

end_position = 1 # with transformed coordinates, 1 is to the end of the drawing canvas
y_coordinate_line = 0.5 
trans = ax.get_yaxis_transform()
ax.plot([start_position, end_position], [y_coordinate_line, y_coordinate_line], color="black", transform=trans, clip_on=False)
plt.show()
```

[image]
It is the black line just above the blue bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44012582/12131013) to get the bounding boxes, you can convert them to the data coordinates using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5467116/12131013) and then find the leftmost value as your `start_position`.

```py
ytickboxes = [l.get_window_extent() for l in ax.get_yticklabels()]
ytickboxesdatacoords = [l.transformed(ax.transAxes.inverted()) for l in ytickboxes]
start_position = min([l.x0 for l in ytickboxesdatacoords])
```

The figure needs to be drawn before the coordinates can be found, so using `fig.draw_without_rendering()` does that. Since you are also using `fig.tight_layout()` you will need to call that just after the drawing, since the coordinates change after calling `tight_layout()`.

In your code, with a longer label, we get:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

bartitles = ["First", "0123456789", "Third"]
barvalues = [4, 3, 5]
total_value = sum(barvalues)

# Figure and axes
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Plot bars
y_pos = list(range(1,4))
ax.barh(y_pos, barvalues, align='center', color='darkgrey')


# Totalbar
y_pos_total = 0  # Position of the totalbar
ax.barh(y_pos_total, total_value, align='center', color='blue')
bartitles.append("Total")
y_pos.append(y_pos_total)

# plot ticks and titles
ax.set_yticks(y_pos)
ax.set_yticklabels(bartitles)

fig.draw_without_rendering()
fig.tight_layout()

ytickboxes = [l.get_window_extent() for l in ax.get_yticklabels()]
ytickboxesdatacoords = [l.transformed(ax.transAxes.inverted()) for l in ytickboxes]
start_position = min([l.x0 for l in ytickboxesdatacoords])

end_position = 1
y_coordinate_line = 0.5 
trans = ax.get_yaxis_transform()
ax.plot([start_position, end_position], [y_coordinate_line, y_coordinate_line], color="black", transform=trans, clip_on=False)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: sorry for my late reply. As I tried your code I get a RuntimeError: Cannot get window extent w/o renderer
I am searching for a solution and I hope it is an easy solution. I would like to add this line functionality in a Python Package hoping it will work for most users.

Comment: @MarcelW1323 I assume you're getting the error on the line before `get_window_extents`. If you add `fig.draw_without_rendering()` before that line, does that work?

Comment: yes the `fig.draw_without_rendering()` solves my error (the traceback was too big to post in my previous comment).

But if I use these bartitles `bartitles = ["First", "0123456789_VERY_LONG", "Third"]` then the line is about 3 characters too short.

What could be a solution for that?

Comment: You need to call `fig.tight_layout()` after the drawing. I've updated the answer to include those two changes.

Comment: `fig.show()` gives the next warning:

`C:\Users\marce\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_7276\654309593.py:36: UserWarning: Matplotlib is currently using module://matplotlib_inline.backend_inline, which is a non-GUI backend, so cannot show the figure.
  fig.show()`


When I replace `fig.show()` with `plt.show()` then no warnings appear and even longer text go great.

Comment: when you replace `fig.show()` with `plt.show()` in your answer, I'll mark this as answered.

Comment: @MarcelW1323 you didn't mention that you're using a Jupyter notebook.

Comment: I am very sorry. As you now can read in my user profile in the section "about", I am coding a Python Package, but when I get something I can't find a solution for, I try to downsize the problem to something small in a Jupyter Notebook what I can test and then post the question.
And I am a member over here for about 3 months and haven't had much interactivity.
Next time I'll tell something about the environment I'm using with the problem.
Thank you for pointing that out so I can grow in better questions.

Comment: @MarcelW1323 Using `fig.show()` is consistent with the explicit "Axes" API being used ([link](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/api_interfaces.html#api-interfaces)). For it to work in a Jupyter notebook, you can use `%matplotlib notebook` instead of `%matplotlib inline`.

Comment: I have read the documentation with the explicit "Axes" API and I think I use that as good as possible. But I haven't read anything about fig.show() and plt.show() in that part of the documentation. Thanks for pointing out anyway.

Comment: Hello jared, thank you for the answer. I would like to use your answer in the Python Package I am currently working on which I like to publish under MIT-license.

In the comment of the function in this Python Package I'd like to write something like:
"Thanks to user jared on stackoverflow.com for helping me out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76502232"

If you wish, I can add your name to the list of contributors.
Or maybe you have the preference to add your code in the package by yourself.

Please let me know your thoughts.

Comment: @MarcelW1323 You can just link to my SO profile and this question. Usernames are transient on SO, so I'm technically `user:12131013`.